# Discouraging link to Lulu or CreateSpace

Tags: marketing, ebook, sales

I am finishing writing a non-fiction (religious) e-book.

It looks like for me that the most effective way to market my writings is to advertise it with AdWords and sell as e-book directly through PayPal (not through a reseller).

I can also make a printed book with Lulu or CreateSpace.

My question: Would adding a link to Lulu or CreateSpace discourage readers to buy my e-book, as they may think that a book on Lulu or CreateSpace is "nonprofessional".

Also e-book purchases would lead money directly to my PayPal account, while with Lulu or CreateSpace I need to wait for payments to accumulate before they send me money. This (printed book) would be a competitor sakes of the e-book.

So, should I sell only e-book or e-book and printed one with Lulu or CreateSpace also?

Comment: Personally, I believe that people will find any book that is advertised through AdWords and purchased through PayPal to be "non-professional", but that's just me. If you're truly intent on self-publishing, you should really use Kindle Direct Publishing and/or Nook Publishing because that's where the vast majority of the e-book readers will be going to look for books.

Answer (score 1):

If you sell through CreateSpace, you can link to the work on Amazon. Since like every book known to man is on Amazon, you should be fine.

What I have done is made the eBook separately and put on Amazon and then published the print version and then through the Amazon Author program I linked the two together.

As long as you aren't using KDP Select (exclusive) you can sell it in as many venues as you want. I have mine also in Google Play, Nook, and Kobo.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the average reader does not know Lulu and CreateSpace from any other online store. But some people would recognize those as POD companies. And some of those would guess that you are a small publisher. And some of those would assume that your book is less professional than a traditional publisher's book.

Here's the reason I don't link to my books on the CreateSpace store: I would like my books to be stocked in bookstores. Bookstores are likely to recognize CreateSpace as a POD company, and be less eager to stock a CreateSpace book on their shelves.

But CreateSpace can distribute your books through Amazon (as Aibrean says) and also lots of other retailers. If your cover and description are professional looking, your book will look no different from any other book in those retailers' stores.

One thing to be aware of with CreateSpace: If you use their free ISBN, they list themselves as the publisher of your book. So the listing on Amazon and other retailers would show CreateSpace as the publisher.

If you want to use your own imprint, you have to buy one of CreateSpace's not-free ISBNs, or (as I do) buy the ISBN from your ISBN registrar and use that.